# Copy and Paste without needing to use the Mouse

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, copy-paste

In previous versions of windows when your were Copying Files (Ctrl-C) then alt-Tab (to the appropriate window) and Pasting (Ctrl-V) using the Keyboard everything could be driven by the keyboard.

With Vista and 7, it seems if you are copying and pasting (and the files exist) in the Destination Location you have to Click the Copy and Replace, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it...

"Do this for the next {n} Conflicts" can be driven by Alt-D, but the "Copy and Replace" and "Don't Copy" are not.

Or is there and have I just missed something?

I'm more than happy to change registry or something to enable Keyboard shortcuts for this.

Comment: Have you tried tabbing to the button, and hitting spacebar?

Comment: lol, so simple works a charm, but still accelerator keys would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this - it works fine on both systems I have access to right now with Windows 7.

But if for some reason you're having trouble with this, I can think of at least three work-arounds:

1. Use either the special key between the right <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to bring up a context menu that will allow you to select the `Paste` option.
2. Use the normal <kbd>Tab</kbd> key a few times so that focus is on the client portion of the window.
3. Hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to show the pull down menu, which will again allow you to choose `Paste`.

---

**Update:**

---

I missed the part at first where the file already exists in the destination folder.  In this case, *I am still able to do it using the keyboard*, however I have to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to toggle between the different Copy/Replace options.

Answer (score 1):

It's getting increasingly common that GUI developers are ignoring keyboard support.  If your application ignores proper keyboard support, you should definitely let the vendor know that there is such a bug (and be sure to include a list of the keystrokes you used to re-produce the bug).

Sometimes applications only support some of the Copy/Cut/Paste keystrokes (which may also be a bug).  For example, they may only support CTRL-Insert (for Paste) while completely ignoring CTRL-P, yet others will get it the other way around.  Unfortunately this leads to a great deal of confusion and inconvenience for users who like to use the keyboard for some [to most] things (I mention these keystrokes in case this helps you).

GUI developers who take the time to make sure that common/basic keyboard and mouse functions are all supported are doing a big favour to many of their users.

Comment: He's talking about Windows Explorer.

Comment: I have looked for a bug reporting form for Windows previously and failed.

Comment: Microsoft has a "Feedback" link on the "Contact us" page on their main web site.  The "Contact us" page is at http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/ (one of the feedback options is for Windows 7).